# How can I install a new language pack in euro truck simulator?

Tags: mods, euro-truck-simulator-2

Is it possible to install a new language pack to euro truck simulator?

I have installed a russian, lithuanian language version of the software and I am interested in changing the language to English from the game itself or by adding a mod.

Please help me if you got an idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to:

> Documents\Euro Truck Simulator 2\profile.

There you can find **config** file. Open it with notepad and find this:

> ... uset g_lang "fi_fi"

I have fi because I'm from Finland. Just change "fi" to your language.

I think you need to add "eng_eng" instead of "fi_fi."

[source](http://www.racedepartment.com/threads/how-to-change-language-to-english.58347/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But although I tried, it didn't work for me. I was wondering whether there is a way to patch the language files rather than re-downloading the whole game.

Comment: You can re-install the game in English pack. From where did you download the game? I might help then.

Comment: Thanks and I will try that. It's a cracked copy I'm afraid. :)

Comment: It's likely "en_uk" for English (or "en_us") if it's using standardized locales (which "fi_fi" appears to suggest).

Answer (score 1):

Go to... Documents\Euro Truck Simulator 2\profile. There you can find config file. Open it with notepad and find this... uset g_lang " " and set g_lang "en_en".